# How to get name of the approver in Email template

Tags: apex, soql, community, workflow, approval-process

Hi friends i'm new to approval process.

I stuck in a place where i need to send an email to the sales rep with either approved or rejected with whom approved or rejected.

I had created a email template like {!ApprovalRequest.Process_Approver} but it is not working.After i had came to know merge fields are not working fine.

So,I though to create a workflow.But how to create a workflow and update a field in opportunity.

Please provide suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Hey i found a solution for this problem.I had created a workflow at the approval and do a field update to a field called **Approved By** in opportunity.Like

```
($User.FirstName)+" "+($User.LastName)
```

And i am using this field in the email template.