# Get a name of an Approver in Approval Assignment Email

Tags: email-template, approval-process

### BACKGROUND

I have an approval process configured for Opportunities:

[image]

I defined the Approval Assignment Email Template as follows:

[image]

I am using 3 users in my org for this case:

1. User Admin - (Profile: System Administrator; Role: n/a) - the user I am using to log into the org. This user is an Opportunity Owner, hence Initial Submitter.
2. Courtney Brown - (Profile: Standard Platform User; Role: Manager (it's under    VP, North American Sales)) - this user is defined as **Manager** for User Admin
3. Allison Wheeler - (Profile: Standard Platform User; Role: VP, North American Sales)

### PROBLEM

When I submit an opportunity for approval, I expect that user Courtney Brown will receive an email (based on the Discount Approval Request template) and see her name in the Greeting section.

[image]

Instead when I check the email, I see the name of the User Admin:

> Dear,
>   User Name: User Admin
>   Process_Assignee: User Admin
>   Process_Approver: User Admin
>
> A new discount request approval is pending. Please log in to your org
>   for details.
>
> Best,
>   User Admin

I assumed that `{!ApprovalRequest.Process_Approver}` would give me the desired output, alas it didn't. I don't understand why this happens and if it is possible to achieve at all?

### WHAT I GOOGLED (did't help)

[How to get the approver name into an HTML email?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B1LGIA0)
[How to get name of the approver in Email template?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130625/how-to-get-name-of-the-approver-in-email-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate text field like `Approver__c` (which will capture logged-in User Name) and update that field from Approval Actions via field update.

And, use this field in the Email template.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Santanu Boral. This is a nice workaround, I just tried it. Anyways, I am still wondering why `{!ApprovalRequest.Process_Approver}` does not return the name for the actual approver ?

Comment: Im not sure, but above solution I have used at my last project